# Angular2 cannot access 'this' inside a promise

Tags: angular

I am unable to call a function inside promise of ng2-sweetalert2 plugin

```
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function(x) {
    this.removeNote(key);
    swal(
    'Deleted!',
    'Your file has been deleted.',
    'success'
    );
}, function(e){
       console.log('Cancelled');
});

removeNote(key){
    this.todo.remove(key);
    this.afService.closeNote(key);
}
```

`this.removeNote()` cause error.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeNote' of undefined
```

How do I overcome this? I used NgZone but i get the same error

Comment: Use `var current = this`

Comment: Arrow functions are the way to go.

Comment: Hey Ashik, I'm looking into setting this sweet alert up in my project, noticed within the documentation it doesn't specify about importing the within the ng module, do you have to do this?

Comment: Hi Code,

Save sweetalert.min.js and sweetalert.min.css from here and include them in your index.html file as normal javascript files `https://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/sweetalert2`. then use this line in your component instead of import `declare var swal: any;`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming you're using TypeScript, you could use the [arrow function expression](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html), which preserves the value of `this`.

```
swal({...}).then((x) => console.log(this)); // now 'this' is your component
```

Comment: works perfectly :)  Also the "x" here now refers to the value returned by the promise's success callback so use it as normal  (x.data.Employee ...)

Answer (score 8):

this is because `this` refers to the promise itself.
do this :

```
let self = this;
   swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function(x) {
    self.removeNote(key);
    swal(
    'Deleted!',
    'Your file has been deleted.',
    'success'
    );
}, function(e){
       console.log('Cancelled');
});

removeNote(key){
    this.todo.remove(key);
    this.afService.closeNote(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like following manner also:

```
swal({})
.then(() => { <your angular 2 service call here...>})
```

Following is the working example:

```
customDialog(id,value){
    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "Message",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
      cancelButtonText: 'No',
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success alertboxmargin',
      cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger alertboxmargin',
      buttonsStyling: false
    }).then(() => {
      this.services.testfunction(table,value,id)
      .subscribe( result => {
        if(result) {
          if(value) {
            swal('Message!','Message.','success')
          }
          else {
            swal('Message!','Message.','success')
          }          
        }
        else {
          swal('Error!','Try again later.','error')
        }        
      });
    },
      function (dismiss) {
      // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
      // 'close', and 'timer'
      if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
        swal('Cancelled','No action performed!','error')
      }
    })//then closing
} // Dialog Closing
```