# why angular throws error Cannot set property 'posts' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

**This is the code I have written in angular/ionic**

```
this.http.get('/assets/xml/app.xml').subscribe(data => {

  xml2js.parseString(data.text(), function(err, result) {
    console.log('result', result);
    this.posts = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log('type of', this.posts);
  });
}, error => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
});
```

This function throws following error when assigning the result to the post variable.

> Cannot set property 'posts' of undefined

Comment: What is the resulting over console? and Is really JSON object and What data type you have mentioned for your post var?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(result))  i think you got undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think it because `this` refers to the promise itself,  you could use the [arrow function expression](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html), which preserves the value of `this`.

Please use following code it will help you.

```
 this.http.get('/assets/xml/app.xml').subscribe(data => {

      xml2js.parseString(data.text(), (err, result) => {

          this.posts = JSON.stringify(result) || {};

       });

  }, error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
 });
```

Please check the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606632/angular2-cannot-access-this-inside-a-promise).

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because `this` is inside the wrong environment. Try getting the instance before accessing that function:

```
    var self = this;
    this.http.get('/assets/xml/app.xml').subscribe(data => {

        xml2js.parseString(data.text(), function (err, result) {
            console.log('result',result);
            self.posts = JSON.stringify(result);
           console.log('type of',this.posts);
        });
    }, error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.it is working by replacing this.post by self.post

Comment: @VedPrakash glad to help, remember to accept the answer if it helped you.